# How to use PrimeNG SplitButton to open the modal that opens the options with one click

Tags: primeng, split-button

I am using PrimeNG SplitButton where I need one click that opens up a modal.

```
<p-splitButton label="Save"  icon="pi pi-plus" [model]="items1"></p-splitButton>
```

There are 2 events, `onDropdownClick` and `onClick`.

I want to open the modal window when user clicks on the button, not when user actually clicks the arrow.

Is this possible?

Comment: it's all here in  primeng samples https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-splitbutton-demo

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand your need, can you create a StackBlitz maybe ?